# How do you make a group of divs fill the containing div

Tags: html, css, grid, jquery-masonry

I'm trying to make a grid of social media icons for my site and i'm struggling to style it properly.

this is what i currently have:

[image]

**HTML:**

```
<div class="masonry-grid-item social-grid">

    <div class="masonry-grid-item w33">
        <i class="icon-facebook" style="font-size:36px;color: #fff;"></i>
    </div>

    <div class="masonry-grid-item w33">
        <i class="icon-twitter" style="font-size:36px;color: #fff;"></i>
    </div>

    <div class="masonry-grid-item w33 w33-last">
        <i class="icon-instagram" style="font-size:36px;color: #fff;"></i>
    </div>

    <div class="grid-clear"></div>

    <div class="masonry-grid-item w33 w33-bot">
        <i class="icon-instagram" style="font-size:36px;color: #fff;"></i>
    </div>

    <div class="masonry-grid-item w33 w33-bot">
        <i class="icon-instagram" style="font-size:36px;color: #fff;"></i>
    </div>

    <div class="masonry-grid-item w33 w33-bot w33-last">
        <i class="icon-instagram" style="font-size:36px;color: #fff;"></i>
    </div>

    <div class="grid-clear"></div>

</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.masonry-grid{margin: 3px;position:relative;}
.masonry-grid-item{width:25%;padding:3px; float: left;}
.masonry-grid-item a{display:block;position:relative;}
.masonry-grid-item a:before{width:100%;height:100%;display:block;content:"";position:absolute;visibility:hidden;opacity:0;filter:alpha(opacity=0);background-color:#000;transition:0.3s all;}
.masonry-grid-item a:hover:before{visibility:visible;opacity:0.2;filter:alpha(opacity=20);}
.masonry-grid-item.w2{width:50%;}
.masonry-grid-item.w3{width:75%;}
.masonry-grid-item.w4{width:100%;}
.masonry-grid img{width:100%;}
.grid-clear {clear:both; width:100%;} 
.w33{width: 31.73%; background: #818990; display: block; padding: 12.2% 0; margin: 0 2.4% 2.4% 0;}
.w33-last{margin-right: 0px;}
.w33-bot{margin-bottom: 0px;}
.wwd {text-align: left; padding: 20px;}
.masonry-grid-item .heading-container { background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.70) none repeat scroll 0 0; bottom: 5%; left: 0; position: absolute; width: 100%; width: 70%; text-align: left; padding: 20px 0 20px 20px;}
.masonry-grid-item h1 { color: #fff; margin: 0; padding: 0;}
.masonry-grid-item h2 {display: block; width: 100%; background: #44ac6d; padding: 10px 20px; color: #fff;}
```

is there any way to make the social media blocks extend to the full height of the div its contained within. And obviously when you resize the window it shrinks or increases with the container.

Here is an example of what i'm looking for

[image]

Answer (score 2):

flexbox will allow you to tell your elements to take up 100% of vertical space.

I've [updated your code to use flex box](https://jsfiddle.net/mLgy9uta/1/) -  you will need to remove your grid-clear elements as they take up vertical space.

The only css i have added is `display:flex;flex-wrap:wrap;` to your container element. (ive added a background color and forced a div height in the fiddle to give an example)

Comment: is flex a css3 standard or just css? also is it compatible with older browsers?

Comment: When i add display:flex;flex-wrap:wrap; to the container div it shrinks everything in height. like the [following](https://gyazo.com/3e2f8b749cd61e2e9d099858a751ca05)

Comment: So i see you added a height of 300px on there i dont have a height on my containing box and i dont want there to be one but rather it to be Auto is this possible?

Comment: yeah i just added it cos if i didn't we'd have an empty div and it wouldn't show anything. In your code, the height would be set by the element to the left

Comment: The element on the left also breaths check out the domain dev.waxmanarchitectural.co.uk to see the page i'm working on. As you can see its all the same height.

Answer (score 0):

You can use flexbox, check this example (similar to you):

**HTML:**

```
  <div class="social-grid">
    <div class="social-item"></div>
    <div class="social-item"></div>
    <div class="social-item"></div>
    <div class="social-item"></div>
    <div class="social-item"></div>
    <div class="social-item"></div>
  </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.social-grid {
  width: 80%;
  height: 300px;
  background: grey;
  //FLEX!
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-content: space-between;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.social-item {
  width: 26%; //more than 1/4
  height: 130px;
  background: green;
}
```